# Remove Fragment 2 from BackStack and pass data to Fragment 1

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, listener

Inside my MainActivity (Demo) I add FragmentDemo 1 to backstack. Inside this fragmentDemo 1, pressing a button opens a new FragmentDemo 2, where I have an edit text. On pressing the button on this second fragment, I want to remove it from backstack and send the data from editText back to FragmentDemo 1.

I am using a listener on Fragment 2, and implementing the methods, but when I run the code I have the following message. `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.teacherapp.activities.Demo@5630fb7must implement Listener`

Demo (Main Activity)

```
public class Demo extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentInterface {
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        addFragment(new FragmentDemo1());
    }

}

@Override
public void onMyFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    addFragment(fragment);
}

private void addFragment(Fragment fragment){
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.demo_container,fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
}
```

FragmentInterface

```
public interface FragmentInterface {
void onMyFragment(Fragment fragment);
}
```

FragmentDemo 1

```
public class FragmentDemo1 extends Fragment implements FragmentInterface, FragmentDemo2.Fragment2CallBack {
Button btnFrag1;
TextView tvFrag1;

public FragmentDemo1() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_demo1, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    btnFrag1 = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment1_button);
    tvFrag1 = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment1_tv);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    btnFrag1.setText("Frag 1: " + String.valueOf(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()));

    btnFrag1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        replaceFragment(new FragmentDemo2());
    });
}

@Override
public void onMyFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    replaceFragment(fragment);
}

private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    getFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.demo_container, fragment).
            addToBackStack(null).
            commit();
}

@Override
public void onDataSent(String myData) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "RECEIVED. "+myData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

FragmentDemo 2

```
public class FragmentDemo2 extends Fragment {
private Button btnFrag2;
private EditText etFrag2;
private Fragment2CallBack listener;


public FragmentDemo2(){}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_demo2,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    btnFrag2=view.findViewById(R.id.fragment2_button);
    etFrag2=view.findViewById(R.id.fragment2_et);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
    btnFrag2.setOnClickListener(v->{
        String info=etFrag2.getText().toString();
        listener.onDataSent(info);
        fm.popBackStack();
    });
}


@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        listener=(Fragment2CallBack) context;
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()+"must implement Listener");

    }
}

public interface Fragment2CallBack{
    void onDataSent(String s);
}

}
```

The result expected is to have fragment 2 removed from backstack and open fragment 1, with received data from fragment 2.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment Back Stack Example.

Refer this url https://www.dev2qa.com/android-fragment-back-stack-example/

Comment: I have check this tutorial, but this is not passing data from fragment 3 to fragment 2 for example.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem in your existing code

**The Context you try to use in FragmentDemo2 is of Demo activity (not of FragmentDemo1) so you can not type cast it to listener when you are trying to attach**

If you want to achieve the same goal with existing code, follow below step

1) Expose API from FragmentDemo2 that will allow to set Listener of type Fragment2Callback

```
public void setListener(Fragment2Callback li) {listener = li;}
```

2) From FragmentDemo1, when you create FragmentDemo2 instance, you also need to set itself as listener to FragmentDemo2

```
FragmentDemo2 frg = new FragemtDemo2()
frg.setListener(this);
replaceFragment(frg);
```

3) Then replaceFragment() from FragmentDemo1

4) remove casting of listener from onAttach() inside FragmentDemo2

So now you have FragmentDemo1 as listener inside FragmentDemo2, which you can use to communicate to fragmentDemo1

I hope this information help you